# How can I call a function in a class that has the setState function from another stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stateful widget that uses the setState method in one of its class methods. I want to convert that widget into an ordinary class so I can use it in Object Oriented Programming. I want to instantiate an instance of that class in another stateful widget and access the methods that have the setState method in them. But I am currently getting this error "The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'MyClass'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'."

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you include your sample code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

The setState method is linked to the state of a stateful Widget. If you want to convert your widget to a Class you can't use setState in it. But you can give the Class a Function as parameter. Anytime you instantiate this Class in a stateful Widget just give the setState from this stateful Widget to the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a better state management solution to your code than stateful widget ,maybe riverpod,
Using [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) you can access the same notifier from other widgets and thus the `setState` functionality plus it has the added benefit of splitting the logic and ui into an mvvm like pattern

Answer (score 0):

`setState` only exists for the `StatefulWidget`. You cannot call `setState` in the class without extending a `StatefulWidget`. So if you want to do that you can use a state management plugin in the Flutter like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get).